# I am trying to write a code in python to get the values from a multiline string and store it in dictionary

Tags: python, string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5x2o.png)This is the string:

```
description = '''add DL3,DL1,DL5,DL6
id7
add DL2,DL3,DL4
id1
id2
id3
add DL3
id1
id2
id3
'''
```

output should be like :

```
action = [{process:add,dl_names:[DL3,DL1,DL5,DL6],id:[id7]},{process:add,dl_names:[DL2, DL3, DL4],id:[id1,id2,id3]},{process:add,dl_names:[DL3],id:[id1,id2,id3]}
```

code i am using:

```
description = '''add DL3,DL1,DL5,DL6
id7
add DL2,DL3,DL4
id1
id2
id3
add DL3
id1
id2
id3
'''

action = {}
con_des = description.splitlines()
#print(con_des)
add_index = []
for lines in con_des:
    if "add" in lines:
        process = "add"
        action["process"] = process
        add_index.append((con_des.index(lines)))
#print(add_index)

for index in add_index:
    temp = con_des[index].split(" ")
    temp_1 = temp[1].split(",")
    dl_list = []
    for dl in temp_1:
        dl_list.append(dl)
    action["dl_names"] = dl_list
    print(action)
```

But i am not getting the desired output, suggest me some approach

Comment: You consistently use `con_des[0]` (the first line) to build temp, when you should use `lines` (the current line). And you should only split on the **first** space: `temp = con_des[0].split(" ", 1)`. And you should do something for the id lines...

Comment: Will the `process` always be `add`?

Comment: yes the process will always be add

Comment: i have changed the code a bit, now i am able to get the process & dl_list but how to add the ids.

Comment: i have attached the output i am getting in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your issues, I modified your split to be able to get all thedl_list so
temp[1:] and added a list to append your actions.

```
action = {}
con_des = description.splitlines()
add_index = []
count = 0
ids = []
actions = []
for lines in con_des:
    if "add" in lines:
        if count == 1:
            actions.append(action)
            action = {}
        ids = []
        process = "add"
        action["process"] = process
        temp = lines.split(" ")
        dl_names = "".join(temp[1:]).split(",")
        action["dl_names"] = dl_names
        action["Ids"] = ids    
    else:
        ids.append(lines)
        count = 1
actions.append(action)
print(actions)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
# 
import re


description = '''add DL3,DL1,DL5,DL6
id7
add DL2, DL3, DL4
id1
id2
id3
add DL3
id1
id2
id3
'''


action = []
item = {}
for line in description.splitlines(): 
    if re.search(r'^add', line):
        if item:
            action.append(item)
            item = {}        
        process, dll = line.split(' ', 1)
        item['process'] = process
        item['dl_names'] = [dl.strip() for dl in dll.split(',')]
        item['id']=[]
    else:
        item['id'].append(line.strip())
if item:
    action.append(item)        

print(action)
```